# Python: Cut off the last word of a sentence?

Tags: python, split, concatenation, text-segmentation

What's the best way to slice the last word from a block of text?

I can think of

1. Split it to a list (by spaces) and removing the last item, then reconcatenating the list.
2. Use a regular expression to replace the last word.

I'm currently taking approach #1, but I don't know how to concatenate the list...

```
content = content[position-1:position+249] # Content
words = string.split(content, ' ')
words = words[len[words] -1] # Cut of the last word
```

Any code examples are much appreciated.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Actually you don't need to split all words. You can split your text by last space symbol into two parts using [rsplit](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit).

Example:

```
>>> text = 'Python: Cut off the last word of a sentence?'
>>> text.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
'Python: Cut off the last word of a'
```

`rsplit` is a shorthand for "reverse split", and unlike regular `split` works from the end of a string.  The second parameter is a maximum number of splits to make - e.g. value of `1` will give you two-element list as a result (since there was a single split made, which resulted in two pieces of the input string).

Comment: With some of the other answers if feel it is necessary to note that rsplit is reverse split (not regex split) and the 1 is maxsplit.

Comment: Just an edge case to note. If there is only one word in the sentence, this solution doesn't remove anything.

Comment: and if you happen to want just the last word in the string, `text.rsplit(' ', 1)[-1]`

Answer (score 20):

You should definitely split and then remove the last word because a regex will have both more complications and unnecessary overhead. You can use the more Pythonic code (assuming content is a string):

```
' '.join(content.split(' ')[:-1])
```

This splits content into words, takes all but the last word, and rejoins the words with spaces.

Answer (score 6):

If you like compactness:

```
' '.join(content.split(' ')[:-1]) + ' ...'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep your current method,  use `' '.join(words)` to concatenate the list.

You also might want to replace `words = words[len[words -1]` with `words = words[:-1]` to make use of list slicing.

Answer (score 4):

OR

```
import re

print ' '.join(re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', text)[:-1])
```

Comment: I guess that regex will give you benefit in case when your word split not only by white spaces. Otherwise rsplit is your choice.

Answer (score 4):

Get last index of space and splice the string

```
>>> text = 'Python: Cut of the last word of a sentence?'
>>> text[:text.rfind(' ')]
'Python: Cut of the last word of a'
```

Comment: This one is 15-20% faster on small strings than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

`' '.join(words)` will put the list back together.

Answer (score 1):

```
        
def replace_ending(sentence, old, new):
    S1 = sentence
    O1 = old
    N1 = new
    # Check if the old string is at the end of the sentence 
    if O1 in S1:
        # Using i as the slicing index, combine the part
        # of the sentence up to the matched string at the 
        # end with the new string
        i = S1.rsplit(' ',1)[0] + str(" ") + N1     
        new_sentence = i
        return new_sentence

    # Return the original sentence if there is no match 
    return sentence
    
print(replace_ending("It's raining cats and cats", "cats", "dogs")) 
# Should display "It's raining cats and dogs"
```

Comment: Im still struggling and a newb, but I did get this to work. hope it helps some, thanks. I added the variables S1 O1 N1 to make it more readable, as they werent on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

**Enother variant is to use an argument "args***"

For example:

```
def truncate_sentences(length, *sentences):
  for sentence in sentences:
    print(sentence[:length])

#call function

truncate_sentences(8, "What's going on here", "Looks like we've been cut off")
```

Would output:

```
"What's g"
"Looks li"
```

Let’s break this down:

1. We have two parameters that our function `truncate_sentences()` defines. The first is a `length` parameter that will specify how many characters we want to keep. The second is a parameter called `sentences` that is paired with the unpacking operator, signifying it will take a variable number of arguments.
2. On each iteration of the function, we are looping through the tuple created by the `sentences` argument (because it is paired with the unpacking operator) and perform a slice on the sentence based on the provided `length` argument. This forces every value in the `sentences` tuple to be cut down in length.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below,

```
def replace_ending(sentence, old, new):
# Check if the old string is at the end of the sentence 
if sentence.endswith(old):
    # Using i as the slicing index, combine the part
    # of the sentence up to the matched string at the 
    # end with the new string
    i = sentence.rsplit(' ',1)[0] + str(" ")
    new_sentence = i + new
    return new_sentence

# Return the original sentence if there is no match 
return sentence
```