# python3 underline the patterm match and chop off the undesired stuff

Tags: python-3.x

I am extacting the output based on the `if else elif` condition and printing the  line starting with pattren `| SUCCESS |`, however i'm trying to add the underline marks for `| SUCCESS |` line just to make distinction.

As i'm using a variable `UNDERLINE` for making that `underline`, Just curious to Know if there is better way to give that `underline`.

```
UNDERLINE = '---------------------------------------------'
def Filter_Suc():
    patt_success = False
    with open("shanghai2_out") as f:
        for line in f:
            if patt_success:
                if "FAILED" in line or "UNREACHABLE" in line:
                    patt_success = False
                else:
                    if "| SUCCESS |" in line:
                        print(UNDERLINE)
                        print(line.rstrip('\n'))
                        print(UNDERLINE)
                    else:
                        print(line.rstrip('\n'))
            elif "| SUCCESS |" in line:
                print(line.rstrip('\n'))
                patt_success = True

Filter_Suc()
```

The above code works well and producing the below output:
However, the output between the `underline` is okay but as i needed only the Hostname ie that is `udalt-chef.preet.com` SO, just wondering how we can chop off the `| SUCCESS | rc=0 >>`

```
---------------------------------------------------------
udalt-chef.preet.com | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
---------------------------------------------------------
domain odence.com
search odence.com global.odence.com
nameserver 192.168.2.14
nameserver 192.168.2.15
```

Sorry for asking too much! However, will appreciate any help in intrim.

Comment: @rahlf23, `strip()`: will remove leading and trailing characters
`lstrip()`:  will remove leading characters
`rstrip()`: will remove trailing characters

Comment: To remove the EOL character from the right side of a string:

`line = line.rstrip('\n')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to strip the extra stuff after the first appearance of something - `' '` in this case:

```
>>> line='udalt-chef.preet.com | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>'
>>> print(line[:line.index(' ')])
udalt-chef.preet.com
```

`index` will return the first index of the given sub-string, and `[:index]` returns everything up until that index, effectively chopping off the rest.

Comment: This looks to be good, i was looking at the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266727/python-cut-off-the-last-word-of-a-sentence

Comment: @krock1516 In that question you are looking for the last occurrence of something, here the first. Still, I would use `rfind` there. In your case you just need to replace your `rstrip` with the above.

Comment: What does mean when we say `index(' ')`  or      `'    '`  specially.

Comment: @krock1516 Like it says in the answer - it returns the index of the first occurrence of the given string (space in this case). It would be the same if you used `line.find(' ')`.