# How to remove multiple substrings at the end of a list of strings in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list of strings:

```
lst =['puppies com', 'company abc org', 'company a com', 'python limited']
```

If at the end of the string there is the word

limited, com or org I would like to remove it. How can I go about doing this?

I have tried;

```
for item in lst:
   j= item.strip('limited')
   j= item.strip('org')
```

I've also tried the replace function with no avail.

Thanks

Comment: FWIW as an addendum to the answers `strip` works on a *character* basis, so `.strip('limited')` is the same as `.strip('deilmt')`, as long as it finds marching *characters* from either end it removes them. Python 3.9.0 added something closer to what you're looking for (`str.removesuffix`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example to remove selected last words from the list of string:

```
lst =['dont strip this', 'puppies com', 'company abc org', 'company a com', 'python limited']
to_strip = {'limited', 'com', 'org'}

out = []
for item in lst:
    tmp = item.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
    if tmp[-1] in to_strip:
        out.append(tmp[0])
    else:
        out.append(item)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['dont strip this', 'puppies', 'company abc', 'company a', 'python']
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this correctly you always want to remove the last word in each sentance?

If that's the case this should work:

```
lst =['puppies com', 'company abc org', 'company a com', 'python limited']

for i in lst:
    f = i.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
    print(f)
```

Returns:

```
puppies
company abc
company a
python
```

> rsplit is a shorthand for "reverse split", and unlike regular split
> works from the end of a string. The second parameter is a maximum
> number of splits to make - e.g. value of 1 will give you two-element
> list as a result (since there was a single split made, which resulted
> in two pieces of the input string). As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266727/python-cut-off-the-last-word-of-a-sentence)

This is also available in the python doc [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit).

Comment: I'd think they only want to remove it if it's one of a number of provided generic words  e.g. "puppies com"-> "puppies" but "puppies butts" -> "puppies butts". Basically [filtering out stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_word).

Comment: thank you - not exactly what I was after but still useful for me :)

Comment: Glad you found it useful. I didn't catch the predefined words to be removed :)